# Pulldown to refresh bugs

Tags: bug, android-app

In the feeds page, when I scroll down I see the refresh "bubble" flicker on my screen.

- App version: 1.0.85
- Device manufacturer: Samsung
- Device model: SM-N920S
- OS version: 6.0.1 (N920SKSU2ZPF4)